# Checking for a value within select box while looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I'm looping over an Ajax result and populating the JSON in a `select` box, but not every JSON result is unique, some contain the same value.

I would like to check if there is already a value contained within the `select` box as the loop iterates, and if a value is the same, not to print it again, but for some reason my `if` check isn't working?

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

var JsonResults = result[i];
var sourcename = JsonResults.Source.DataSourceName;

if ($('.SelectBox').find('option').text != sourcename) {
    $('.SelectBox').append('<option>' + sourcename + '</option>');                             
   }
}
```

Comment: you should fix the creation of that JSON not to contain dup.

Comment: `$('.SelectBox').find('option').text()` will just return the text of the first option. This loop won't tell you if there's already an option with that text.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the duplicates from the array, with `result = $.unique(result)`?

Comment: why are you not setting value in option? why you prefer option text as a selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text()` is a method, so it needs parentheses, and it returns text of all `<option>` concatenated. There are better ways to do this, but an approach similar to yours can be by using a variable to save all the added text, so we can check this variable instead of having to check in the `<option>` elements:

```js
var result = ["first", "second", "first", "third", "second"];

var options = {};
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var JsonResults = result[i];
  var sourcename = JsonResults; //JsonResults.Source.DataSourceName;

  if (!options[sourcename]) {
    $('.SelectBox').append('<option>' + sourcename + '</option>');
    options[sourcename] = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="SelectBox"></select>
```

Note: I only used `var sourcename = JsonResults;` for the demo. Use your original line instead.

Answer (score 0):

`.text` is a function, so you have to call it to get back the text in the option

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

  var JsonResults = result[i];
  var sourcename = JsonResults.Source.DataSourceName;

  if ($('.SelectBox').find('option').text() != sourcename) {
    $('.SelectBox').append('<option>' + sourcename + '</option>');                             
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the jQuery method is `.text()` - it's not a static property. For another, your `.find` will give you the *combined* text of every `<option>`, which isn't what you want.

Try deduping the object before populating the HTML:

```
const sourceNames = results.map(result => result.Source.DataSourceName);
const dedupedSourceNames = sourceNames.map((sourceName, i) => sourceNames.lastIndexOf(sourceName) === i);
dedupedSourceNames.forEach(sourceName => {
  $('.SelectBox').append('<option>' + sourceName + '</option>');
});
```